# Conditionally setting the target property on h:setPropertyActionListener

Tags: jsf

I have a `h:commandButton` that needs to set a property inside a bean. Depending on the value of a variable, I may need to set a different property. Here's the code I tried

```
<h:commandButton value="Procedi">
    <f:ajax event="click" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        target="#{comparisonSide eq 'Left' ? compareManaged.optionalLeft : compareManaged.optionalRight}"
        value="#{comparisonSide eq 'Left' ? optionalManaged.selectedOptionalsLeft : optionalManaged.selectedOptionalsRight }" />
</h:commandButton>
```

This doesn't seem to work because of the syntax I tried to use in the `target` attribute of the `setPropertyActionListener` (that is, you can't use ternary operator there).

Is there a way to achieve this sort of conditional targeting without littering my code with `c:if`'s?

P.S. I'm using myfaces and richfaces if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you rightfully stated in the comment, is that `target` attribute determines the property to set the value with and JSF can't find it.

You can split the two property updates in two separate `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` instances and each action listener update the relevant property with the relevant value.

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener
    target="#{compareManaged.optionalLeft}"
    value="#{comparisonSide eq 'Left' ? optionalManaged.selectedOptionalsLeft : '' }" />
<f:setPropertyActionListener
    target="#{compareManaged.optionalRight}"
    value="#{comparisonSide eq 'Left' ? '' : optionalManaged.selectedOptionalsRight }" />
```

You can of course also do the job directly in your action, or actionlistener method.

Comment: maybe it wasn't clear in my question, but the two assignments are mutually exclusive. EDIT: oh, now I see what you did. anyway, optionalLeft and optionalRight are Lists of objects, and they must not be overwritten. Yeah, maybe I should have stated the problem a bit more in depth

Comment: It was, but I proposed to equate the other property to an empty string.

Comment: Maybe then you've got a design issue in this case?

Comment: how so? I'm still learning so any pointer is greatly appreciated

Comment: You didn't state anything regarding your functional requirement, so I'm not able to provide you with further ideas.

Comment: Regarding your issue, you can set the right list in your action/actionlistener method by injecting the bean whose property serves as the value for the list and assigning the right list to a right property.

Comment: Seems to be the best solution so far. Would you please post your last comment as an answer so I can accept it?